# Citable reference for "amphichiral knot" being equivalently definable with "self-homeomorphism" or "self-diffeomorphism"?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory

**Question.** Is there a precise citable reference explicitly saying that in defining "amphirical knot" it is equivalent

to either say

"orientation-reversing self-*homeomorphism* of the 3-sphere"

or

"orientation-reversing self-*diffeomorphisms* of the 3-sphere"?

Comment: I'd say you should refer to Moise's book.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moise%27s_theorem, but you would have to do a bit more work since you are dealing with a relative version of this problem. It will work though. If you are just writing a paper, simply refer to Moise.